# Controlar valor [null] en mapeo de JSON con JSONArray()

Tags: java, json, jsonobject, groovy, jsonarray

Estoy intentando cargar miles de usuarios en iteraciones de 1000 en 1000 hasta que encuentre que hay menos de 1000 y corte.

Mi problema se encuentra a la hora de mapear el value.Si encuentra un atributo del usuario con valor [null],entre corchetes.Es la primera vez que realizo una llamada a un servidor y me devuelve un atributo donde no es capaz de leerlo.He intentado controlarlo en el método donde leo el JSON pero no consigo llegar a ello.

Os muestro el método para pasar la lista a un objeto y leerlo y otra funcion donde le paso toda la info en JSON para parsear.

**Método para parsear**

```
public static List<UserConnectorObject> fromJSONParser(String data, String identityKey) throws Exception{
      List<UserConnectorObject> userList;

      try{
        userList = new ArrayList<UserConnectorObject>();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String json = data;
        JSONObject joObject = new JSONObject(json)
        println(" Resultados:"+joObject.getInt("totalResults"));

        JSONArray schemaJsonArray = joObject.getJSONArray("schemas");
          for (int i = 0; i < schemaJsonArray.length(); i++) {
               println(" item: "+schemaJsonArray.get(i));
              }

              JSONArray resourcesJsonArray = joObject.getJSONArray("Resources");
               for (int i = 0; i < resourcesJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject item = (JSONObject) resourcesJsonArray.get(i);
                   println("Pintame el item "+item)
                   writeJSON(item);                                               

               }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;

    } finally {
      println("Finish fromJSON() method");
    }

    return userList;
  }

  private static Map<String, Object> writeJSON (JSONObject item) throws Exception{
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Iterator<String> keys = item.keys();
        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Object value = item.get(key);
            if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
              } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                  value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
              }   
            map.put(key, value);
            println("Pintame el value "+value);
        }   
        return map;
    }
```

**Lista de atributos JSON de usuarios**

```
if (gesdenResponse != null) {
        if (gesdenResponse.getResponseCode() == 200)
        {
          if (gesdenResponse.getOutput() != null && !gesdenResponse.getOutput().isEmpty())
          {
            List<UserConnectorObject> userList = GesdenUtils.fromJSONParser(gesdenResponse.getOutput(), GesdenConstants.USER_IDENTITY_KEY);
            rt.setUserList(userList);
            log.info("Search successfully returned " + userList.size() + " result(s)");
            rt.setStatus(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS);

          } else {
            log.info("Search without results");
          }

        } else {
          log.info("Search failed, search service returned HTTP code " + gesdenResponse.getResponseCode());
          rt.setErrorText("Search service returned HTTP code " + gesdenResponse.getResponseCode());
        }
      }
```

**SALIDA**

```
Pintame el item {"apellidos":"Gallara Forner","eCorreo":"mgallara@pex.es","oculPac":false,"oculPac2":false,"admGrp":"N","fecHact":[null],"userName":"Maribel","rptGeneral":true,"telef":"","idTipoEsp":19,"dirRpExp":"","idCol":0,"usrRido":"","idPerfil":15,"usuario":"mgallara","fecDact":[null],"fecPass":"2019-07-24 14:01:00.0","usrBloq":false,"dni":"12345678A"}
Pintame el value Gallara Forner
Pintame el value mgallara@pex.es
Pintame el value false
Pintame el value false
Pintame el value N
Finish fromJSON() method
2019-09-26 15:41:35.974  INFO 3851 --- [    container-1] c.groovy.gesden.SearchScriptConnector    : An exception ocurred while searching users in target system: No signature of method: static connector.groovy.gesden.common.ConnectorUtils.toList() is applicable for argument types: (org.json.JSONArray) values: [[null]]
Possible solutions: notify(), wait(), split(groovy.lang.Closure), collect(), wait(long), toJSON(java.util.List)
```

Comment: tuve un problema similar tuve que convertir ese null a "null" en la consulta a la base de datos,

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución,era algo que no estaba controlando y es muy simple.Con un simple `if` en el sitio apropiado se soluciona todo :).Simplemente hay que tracear y se da con el problema. Os dejo el código por si le puede servir de ayuda a alguien que quiera recorrer un JSON , en este caso castear un tipo de dato primitivo a cualquier otro tipo de dato.

```
private static Map<String, Object> writeJSON (JSONObject item) throws Exception{
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Iterator<String> keys = item.keys();
        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Object value = item.get(key);
            if (value instanceof JSONArray){
              //Añadimos esta validacion ya que algun atributo puede venir como [null] y JSONArray no es capaz de castear el elemento
                 if(value.equals("null")){
                    value = toList((JSONArray) value);
                 }
            } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                  value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
            println("Pintame el value "+value);

        }   
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Si crees que esto es solución a tu problema puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.